# Unable to stop outer scroll when inner scroll comes on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I am trying to add a similar scrolling effect as in http://www.uber.com/, means when a child (inner) scroll comes on screen then the parent (outer) scroll should stop and when the child (inner) scroll completes the parent (outer) scroll should start.

I have tried this on one of my website, but it is not working perfectly.

And here is a part of JS which I have tried so far to stop the outer scroll:

```
           var movement=$("#movement_val").val();

           if ((movement=='up') && (sectionIndex==0)){
               enableScroll();
           }
           else if ((movement=='down') && (sectionIndex==2)){
               enableScroll();
           }
           else{
               disableScroll(); 
           }
```

Comment: How about using custom scroll bar plugin? - Please refer this  http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/nested_scrollbars_demo.html

Comment: This scrolling effect is called Parallax Scrolling. Google for it.

Comment: I've removed two dead links from this old question. It can be closed as lacking an [mcve].